# In general relativity, how to get geometric velocity from 4-vector velocity field?

Tags: general-relativity, vectors, velocity, vector-fields

Currently, I‘m listening to the lecture of Prof. Hughes (https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/8-962-general-relativity-spring-2020/video_galleries/video-lectures/).

In General, I‘m able to follow the lecture, but I got stuck at one of the first assignments.

In problem set 1 (https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/8-962-general-relativity-spring-2020/d603dce52718517aad26bf8a216a4dab_MIT8_962S20_pset01.pdf) one should determine the spatial velocity with a vector field $U^\alpha$ given (question 2 (b) ):

$$
U^\alpha = (1+t^2,t^2,\sqrt 2 t,0) 
$$
In addition, a scalar $\rho $ is given by

$$\rho = x^2+t^2-y^2 $$

The given $U^\alpha $ is timelike and I know that the 4 velocity is connected to the spatial velocity by

$$ u_\alpha =(\gamma, \gamma \vec v) $$

However, I‘m not able to transform the first element from $1+t^2$ to $\gamma $, which is badly annoying me. Has anyone an idea how to attack this one?

Comment: You don't need to actually find $\gamma$ to show that $U^\alpha$ is suitable as a four-velocity velocity vector (assuming that's what you're trying to do.)  But if $U^\alpha$ is in fact a four-velocity, then $U^t = \gamma = 1 + t^2$.  So I'm kind of confused about what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In the task in the problem set it was asked to find the spatial velocity $\vec v$ in $U=(\gamma,\gamma \vec v)$ so thought I need to bring $U$ into this shape to be able to extract $\vec v$. According to your answer I would simply divide all spatial coordinates by $1+t^2$ to get the components of $\vec v$. Would this be correct?

Answer (score 0):

If $U^\alpha$ is a 4-velocity, then its norm has to be equal to unity.
I assume that you are working in a Minkowski spacetime with metric signature (-,+,+,+). This implies that

$$(U^{\alpha})^2 = -(1+t^2)^2 + (t^2)^2 + (\sqrt{2}t)^2 = -1 \,.$$

Hence, $t = 0$ is a possible solution, which gives $\vec{v} = 0$.